# xcode4 parameter of incompatible type

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios4

A project that runs fine on Xcode3, fails to compile on Xcode4 with this error:

> file://localhost/users/Ishaq/Projects/game01/libs/cocos2d/CCLayer.m:
>   error: Semantic Issue: Sending 'ccColor4B' (aka 'struct _ccColor4B')
>   to parameter of incompatible type 'CIColor *'

the code that throws this error is below (from cocos2d-iphone `CCLayer.m`):

```
+ (id) layerWithColor:(ccColor4B)color
{
     return [[[self alloc] initWithColor:color] autorelease];
}
```

Somehow Xcode thinks this code is calling `- (id)initWithColor:(CIColor *)color;` of `CIImage` (inside `CIImage.h`). How can I set Xcode's brain straight? ;-)

Comment: I haven’t been able to fix the problem, for now I am sticking with Xcode3 for this project.

Comment: problem fixed, accepted iPadDevZone.com’s answer below

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've got the same problem. My resolution was to explicitly cast it proper type which helps the compiler to find the proper class. So the code looks like this:

```
return [[(CCColorLayer*)[self alloc] initWithColor:color] autorelease];
```

Comment: that worked for me. You know something's gonna be fun with the lesson 1 sample code that comes with the book doesn't even compile!

Comment: In my case `return [[(ColorLayer*)[self alloc] initWithColor:color] autorelease];`

Answer (score 1):

You could change `self` to the actual classname `CCLayer` which should point Xcode in the right direction.

Comment: that's weird, maybe try cleaning the project and building again?

Comment: yeah, really weird, have tried cleaning up again. even tried commenting the method, it still gives me this error. :(

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened for me when using the "LLVM GCC 4.2" compiler.  Changing the compiler setting to "Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0" fixed it.

Comment: Ok sorry :( please do comment again if you do find out the fix.

Comment: i didn’t notice iPadDevZone.com’s answer above, that fixed it for me.  :) although now I have a few other errors to take care of, but they are different.

Comment: Hmm yes, that seems obvious now.  Doh!